# Adding black stripe to website

Tags: html, css

I need a huge faver from you. I have build a website, his address is:
http://www.thetaonline.co.il/ThetaOnline

I would like to add a black strip on the right side of the white rectangle in the middle, like in the left side of the white rectangle.

Can you please help me to, by seeing the source code behind the page, tell me the easiest way to do it?

Thanks in advanced, Tal.

Comment: It would be easier for us to know what you want to achieve, if you could give us a picture

Comment: I can't add a picture because I have a low reputation, can I send you an email with the picture with what I want to add?

Comment: You could upload the picture to your webserver or free image host and link to it. I don't see a white triangle, personally.

Comment: White rectangle, @Chuck. Not triangle.

Comment: How odd. I was sure it said "triangle" when I got here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#main {
    margin: 0;   /* Keep this */
    float: left; /* Change this to left */
    width: 90%;  /* Change this from 95% to 90% */
}
```

You should try doing it yourself first tho, since the point of Stackoverflow is a for asking questions, not asking for people to do stuff for you. =)

Comment: The black strip on the left is already in float with the right white and black rectangles, so I want to make a float between the white rectangle and the right black strip that I want to add

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://imgur.com/Fm90W If so, the CSS I posted does exactly that.